Replacing a string in a byte slice with a new string of different length without interfering with other data
I’m working on some code where I know the start position of a string in a packet, and I know the string’s terminator, which is 0x00 0x00 0x00. I need to replace the old string with a new one, but I’m having a problem: the new string might be larger or smaller than the old one, and I can’t interfere with the other bytes in my packet. Can someone help me with this?
func replaceString(data []byte, newString string, startPos int) error {
    // Checks if the start position is valid
    if startPos >= len(data) || startPos < 0 {
        return fmt.Errorf("start position out of bounds")
    }

    terminatorPos := bytes.Index(data[startPos:], []byte{0x00, 0x00, 0x00})
    if terminatorPos == -1 {
        return fmt.Errorf("termination sequence not found")
    }

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    packets.WriteS(buf, "testing long string")

    return nil
}

func WriteS(buf *bytes.Buffer, value string) {
    // Converter a string para UCS-2
    ucs2 := utf16.Encode([]rune(value))

    // Escrever os bytes da string em UCS-2 (little-endian)
    for _, char := range ucs2 {
        buf.WriteByte(byte(char & 0xff))        // Byte menos significativo
        buf.WriteByte(byte((char >> 8) & 0xff)) // Byte mais significativo
    }

    // Escrever o terminador null (2 bytes de 0x00)
    buf.WriteByte(0x00)
    buf.WriteByte(0x00)
    buf.WriteByte(0x00)
}


You obviously can't write a different number of bytes in the same number of bytes, so some other parts of the packet are going to have to change. Can you show a [mre] along with what you expect the result to be?

[1/2] To me, it looks like you're asking "how do I replace a block of bytes of length N in a middle of a slice with another block of length M, possibly M != N?" The answer goes like this: you construct a new slice which contains the block of bytes before the block to be replaced begins, then the new block, then the block which is past the old one to be replaced. How to do that, is explained in https://go.dev/wiki/SliceTricks.

[2/2] Of course, you can possibly do an optimization: if you know the length of the new block is equal to the length of the old one, you just do "in place" replacement (say, call copy with the destination being the subslice of the original slice, or do a plain for loop copying bytes), and if the new block is shorter, you can do the same, following by the "moving copy" of the original trailer block (the one which follows the block to be replaced)—moving it "left" by as many bytes the new block is shorter. You then subslice the whole slice to have the new (shorter) length.

Here is a solution that returns a modified []byte, or an error. It is designed to tolerate single UTF-16 NUL's prior to the terminator. It requires Go 1.21 for slices.Replace.
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "slices"
    "unicode/utf16"
)

func replaceString(data []byte, newString string, startPos int) ([]byte, error) {
    if startPos >= len(data) || startPos < 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("start position out of bounds")
    }
    zero := 0
    terminatorPos := -1
    for i, b := range data[startPos:] {
        // Assumes UTF-16 i.e. 2 bytes per character. The terminator must
        // begin on an even-numbered byte.
        if b != 0 {
            zero = 0
        } else if zero > 0 || i%2 == 0 {
            zero += 1
            if zero == 3 {
                terminatorPos = i + 1 - zero
                break
            }
        }
    }
    if terminatorPos == -1 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("termination sequence not found")
    }
    ucs2 := utf16.Encode([]rune(newString))
    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    for _, char := range ucs2 {
        buf.WriteByte(byte(char & 0xff))
        buf.WriteByte(byte((char >> 8) & 0xff))
    }
    return slices.Replace(data, startPos, startPos+terminatorPos, buf.Bytes()...), nil
}

func main() {
    // [42 97 0 98 0 99 0 0 0 0 42]
    fmt.Println(replaceString([]byte{42, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 42}, "abc", 1))
}

